# Where I made a mistake during factoring $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

In order to factor the expression, due to symmetry of coefficients if $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are zeros of  $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ then $\frac{1}{r_1}, \frac{1}{r_2} , \frac{1}{r_3}$ are also zeros. So we can rewrite:

$$x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=(x^2-(r_1+\frac{1}{r_1})x+1)+(x^2-(r_2+\frac{1}{r_2})x+1)(x^2-(r_3+\frac{1}{r_3})x+1)$$

And it can be written as:$$x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=(x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+1)(x^2+cx+1)$$

$$=x^6+(a+b+c)x^5+(3+ab+ac+bc)x^4+(abc+a+b+c)x^3+(3+ab+ac+bc)x^2+(a+b+c)x+1$$

In orther to find$a,b,c$ I should solve the system :

${ \begin{cases}{a+b+c=1} \\ {ab+ac+bc=-2} \\ {abc=0}\end{cases} }$

from the equation $abc=0$ We have $a=0$ (Since our derivation was symmetric in $a,b,c$ it doesn't matter to put $a=0$ or $b=0$ or $c=0$).

${ \begin{cases}{b+c=1} \\ {bc=-2}\end{cases} }$

and from that we have $b=2$ , $c=-1$ , $a=0$

So I get :

$$x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=(x^2+1)(x^2+2x+1)(x^2-x+1)=(x^2+1)(x+1)^2(x^2-x+1)$$

But my answer is wrong because if we multiply the equation by $x-1$ We should obtain $x^7-1$. But:

$$(x-1)(x^2+1)(x+1)^2(x^2-x+1)=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1)=(x^4-1)(x^3+1) \ne x^7-1$$

I checked my answer several times but I couldn't find my mistake.

Comment: The product should have term $(abc+\color{red}2a+\color{red}2b+\color{red}2c)x^3$

Comment: You can factor it in this way but r_1 + 1/r_1 will still be an algebraic irrational

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Noe that
$$
(x^2+1)(x+1)^2(x^2-x+1)=
x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 + x + 1,
$$
so you forgot a factor $2$, as remarked above. The polynomial
$$
\Phi_7(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6
$$
is irreducible over the integers and over the rational numbers by the Gauss lemma and Eisenstein's criterion. Therefore such a factorization cannot hold.

Comment: J.W. Tanner already pointed out where that was.

Comment: by Gauss? I think we need Eisenstien

Comment: @LinAlg This is why I said "as remarked above".

Comment: Ok I made a mistake as you pointed out.  Is it possible to continue the method I used and find $a,b,c$ from the system:  $${ \begin{cases}{a+b+c=1} \\ {ab+ac+bc=-2} \\ {abc=-1}\end{cases} }$$and how to solve the system actually?!

Comment: $a,b,c$ are roots of $t^3-t^2-2t+1$ by Vieta's theorem. @Soheil For solving the cubic you can use Cardano's formula.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Thank you very much.

Comment: @Soheil. Using the trigonometric method, $(a,b,c)$ are given by$$t_k=\frac{1}{3} \left(2 \sqrt{7} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(2 \pi  k-\sec
   ^{-1}\left(-2 \sqrt{7}\right)\right)\right)+1\right)\quad \text{with}\quad k=0,1,2$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks, But I am not familiar with trigonometric method.  Can you send some links or references for this method?

Comment: @Soheil https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function

Answer (score 1):

To factor over $\mathbb{R}$, note that:
$$
\begin{align}
x^6+\cdots+1
&=\frac{1}{x-1}\left(x^7-1\right)
\end{align}
$$
where $x^7-1$ has its roots being the complex seventh roots of unity. One such root is of course $1$, while the other six pair up with their complex conjugate:
$$
\begin{align}
&x^6+\cdots+1\\
&=\frac{1}{x-1}(x-1)\left(x-e^{2\pi i/7}\right)\left(x-e^{-2\pi i/7}\right)\left(x-e^{4\pi i/7}\right)\left(x-e^{-4\pi i/7}\right)\left(x-e^{6\pi i/7}\right)\left(x-e^{-6\pi i/7}\right)\\
&=\left(x^2-2\cos(2\pi/7)x+1\right)\left(x^2-2\cos(4\pi/7)x+1\right)\left(x^2-2\cos(6\pi/7)x+1\right)
\end{align}
$$
This is the full factorization over $\mathbb{R}$.

Any factorization over $\mathbb{Q}$ would have to be composed of polynomials where complex conjugate roots are paired. So a factorization over $\mathbb{Q}$ is either trivial (the original polynomial is irreducible) or with all other factorings under consideration, at least one of those quadratic polynomials would be present, and  one of $\cos(2\pi/7)$, $\cos(4\pi/7)$, $\cos(6\pi/7)$ is rational. But the only way that the cosine of a rational multiple of $\pi$ can be a rational number is if said cosine is $0$, $\pm\frac12$, or $\pm1$. (This last fact not trivial, just something I've memorized. A proof is [accessible](https://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/jahnel/Preprints/cos.pdf) though.) And of course those three cosine values are not in $\{0,\pm\frac12,\pm1\}$. Therefore the original polynomial must be irreducible.